# How to use preparedstatement to update data in SQL Server column with "Geometry"

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, gis

I want to update the data in column of table with data type of Geometry. I have an GIS webservice that returns the JSON response with X and Y values. I have retrieved those values along with other values required for other string and Int data type column from JSON. Java code within the application is working fine but my question is how do you "update" data with data type of "Geometry".

In the database there is some sample data with in the following format "0x346C0000010CFFC7C50034B01B41BC2D52FF8F660941" . I have no clue how I can use preparestatement to set the X&Y data in this format. Any insight or advice will be helpful.

I know how to query and convert this data after doing some research which as follows but don't know what is to be done in my program.

```
SELECT Shape.STX as x ,Shape.STY as y from Test
WHERE ID=14082
```

**UPDATE**

```
"Insert INTO Test(column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, geom)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,ST_GeomFromText(?, 2100));"

pst.setString(5,"POINT("+lat+" "+log+")" );
```

I found this solution for now but I have no clue what "2100" means in the above query. Maybe it's wrong, I don't have a set up now but will update this post if I find any solution with the update query. In the meantime if any one has any solution feel free to update the post.

Comment: Found something with "STPointFromText" is that right direction?

Comment: Can I use Standard JDBC driver for "STPointFromText"? is there any other method that I can use from standard JDBC driver which will perform the same result as ST_GeomFromText if I can't use this method.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can insert and retrieve Spatial Data. HTH.

---

**Inserting and retrieving Spatial Data in SQL Server:**

Spatial Data mainly uses 2 data types:

1. Geometry - for 2d on flat surface.
2. Geography - for 3d on global / round surface.

All spatial data is stored in x-y coordinates. To handle spatial data, the DML statements use Spatial-Functions written as string (within 'quotes') as they are in WKT (Well Known Text) format, e.g. 'POINT(5 3)' (Note: WKT is a text mark-up language used to represent vector geometry objects). Following are some common functions: (For detailed explanation please refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)):

**Data Insertion**:

Following functions can be used in INSERT statement. e.g.

`INSERT INTO Tbl1 (mySpatialColumn) 
 Values ('LineString(-1 -2, 6 7))`

•   'Point(int x int y)' : a 0-dimensional object or just a point.

•   'LineString(x1 y1, x2 y2, x.. y..)'
[image]

•   'CircularString(x1 y1, x2 y2, x.. y..)'
[image]

•   'CompoundCurve(x1 y1, x2 y2, x.. y..)'
[image]

•   'Polygon(x1 y1, x2 y2, x.. y..)'
[image]

•   'CurvePolygon(x1 y1, x2 y2, x.. y..)'

•   'MultiPoint': a collection of multiple points, e.g.: 'MultiPoint((2 3), (7 8 9.5))'

•   'MultiLineString((x1 y1, x.. y..), (x1 y1, x.. y..))': multiple lines, e.g.: 'MultiLineString((1 1, 3 5), (-5 3, -8 -2))'
[image]

•   'MultiPolygon((x1 y1, x.. y..), (x1 y1, x.. y..))': collection of multiple Polygons.
[image]

**Data Retrieval:**

Following functions can be used in SELECT statement. e.g.:

```
SELECT mySpatialCol.ToSting(), mySpatialCol.AsGml() FROM Tbl1;
```

•   .ToString(): displays results in the same format as initially inserted i.e. as source-function with parameter values (instead of the hex values), e.g.: colName.ToString() will show: LineString(0 0, 7 8).

•   .AsGml(): converts and returns values in GML/XML format (instead of returning hex or source-function), e.g. for a LineString() value - colName.AsGml() will return:

```
<LineString xmlns="www.example.com/gml"><posList>0 0 7 8</posList></LineString>
```

Note: In SSMS (Management Studio), you can view the retrieved results either as Data itself (which are hexadecimal values) or you can view the Spatial Results i.e. the shapes / diagrams (see example below):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eddie for some notes...but do u know if i can use POINT with usual Sql JDBC driver for sql server? Or  i need some other jdbc driver for POINT?

Comment: Hi, you don't need specific JDBC driver to be able to use any Spatial functionality of the SQL Server (it's been around since Sql Server 2012). You should be able to use the POINT() function as long as you can connect to the dbms from your Java code. AFAIK, it will get processed by SQL's engine (and not by JVM).

Comment: The sql server i am working with is 2008.....thats why i wasnt sure if the query that i posted is going to work or not with my Java code. Do u have any insights into what i need to do in sql server 2008 ?

Comment: Also from your notes i can see in the result tab the data is in hex value so please correct if my assumption is wrong, when we use point function does it automatically converts it into hex value?

Comment: SS 2008 has basic support for spatial data, Point class is there (in 2008) and yes data entered using Point() gets converted and stored in hex.  please refer to the [official paper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226407) published by Microsoft that contains the spatial methods and classes' Compatibility levels i.e. availability in SS 2008/12 - see the Appendix I & II.

Comment: Thanks @eddie kumar